# Laravel WireUI undefined

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Me pareció práctico este paquete de Laravel Livewire llamado WireUI lo tengo en un proyecto y me empezó a dar un error en todos los componentes datatpicker de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me pasa en todas las páginas de mi proyecto.

En la consola me figuran múltiples errores que apuntan a:

> Uncaught ReferenceError

Exactamente 516 errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

486 Warnings:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En mi localhost anda bien.**

Pruebas realizadas:

Reinstalé todos los paquetes:

```
composer install
composer update
```

Actualice la versión de PHP 8.2 a la 8.3.
Volví a subir el proyecto con casi todos los archivos de mi localhost.

¿Qué otras pruebas puedo realizar?

Answer (score 0):

¿Te fijaste en hacer la instalación del paquete que sea la versión 1?

La documentación del paquete muestra este mensaje:

```
V2 Warning: This is a work in progress. Please use the V1 version for now.
```

[Link a la advertencia](https://packagist.org/packages/wireui/wireui#user-content-v2-warning-this-is-a-work-in-progress-please-use-the-v1-version-for-now:%7E:text=V2%20Warning%3A%20This%20is%20a%20work%20in%20progress.%20Please%20use%20the%20V1%20version%20for%20now.)

Otra opción para que controles es que tengas Composer 2.

En versiones antiguas de Composer, solía haber una opción --dev para instalar las dependencias de desarrollo, pero desde Composer 2, la gestión de dependencias de desarrollo se maneja de manera diferente.

En Composer 2, las dependencias de desarrollo se manejan automáticamente y ya no se necesita especificar --dev al ejecutar composer install. Composer 2 introduce un enfoque más simple y eficiente para la instalación de dependencias y utiliza una combinación de archivos composer.json y composer.lock para gestionar el entorno de desarrollo y producción.

Entonces, si tenés Composer 1, deberías hacerle el install del paquete con `--dev`.

Espero que alguna de estas opciones te ayude a solucionar tu duda.